# Laravel 5 Eloquent Modelo error

Tags: php, laravel, sql, eloquent, model

Hola comunidad de Stackoverflow, tengo este error mientras trato de utilizar consulta entre modelos y relaciones en Laravel 5.3:

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::adminis()

Estos son mis modelos:

> Relacion Uno a Muchos con respecto al segundo.

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Modelos;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class srh_inf_persona extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'srh_inf_personas';

        protected $primaryKey = ['infp_cedula'];

        public function adminis()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Modelos\srh_infa_admini');
        }
    }
```

> Y este el otro modelo en relacion inversa de Uno a Muchos.

```
    <?php

    class srh_inf_admini extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'srh_inf_adminis';
    public $timestamps = 'false';

    protected $primaryKey = ['infa_cedula'];

    public function persona()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Modelos\srh_inf_persona');
    }
}
```

> Este es el controlador donde hago la consulta:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Controladores;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Modelos\srh_inf_persona; // Llamado del modelo SRH_INF_PERSONA
use App\Modelos\srh_inf_admini; // Llamado del modelo SRH_INF_PERSONA

class SolicitudController extends Controller
{
    public function nuevasolicitud($ced)
    {       
        $consulta = srh_inf_persona::select('infp_cedula')->adminis()
        ->where('infp_cedula',$ced)
        ->first();

        return view('permisos.solicitud',[ 'personas' => $consulta ]);
    }

}
```

Que podrá ser? no se si es algo en las relaciones o es una mala consulta.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: creo que es `srh_inf_persona::select('infp_cedula')->where('infp_cedula',$ced)->first()->adminis();` puedes probar eso?

Comment: Sería más fácil si nos contaras lo que pretendes hacer con dichos modelos y lo que deseas obtener en `$consulta`.

Answer (score 0):

Esta incorrecto lo que quieres hacer. Creo que lo que quieres hacer es utilizar un scope query. Lo que necesitas hacer para que te funcione es agregar un metodo en la clase de "srh_inf_persona" de la siguiente manera.

```
public function scopeAdminis($query)
{
    // Restricciones que quieres agregar
    return $query;
}
```

Agregando este metodo no debe de haber error.

O si lo que quieres hacer es cargar la relacion, tienes que hacerlo con el metodo with

```
$consulta = srh_inf_persona::select('infp_cedula')
        ->with('adminis')
        ->where('infp_cedula',$ced)
        ->first();
```